# Custom MediaTypeFormatter not being used for deserialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, deserialization, asp.net-web-api2, mediatypeformatter

I have a simple `MediaTypeFormatter` like so:

```
public class SomeFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{
    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(SomeRequest);
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(SomeResponse);
    }

    public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using (readStream)
            {
                return (object)new SomeRequest();
            }
        });
    }

    public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // ReSharper disable once MethodSupportsCancellation
        return ReadFromStreamAsync(type, readStream, content, formatterLogger);
    }

    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 255; i++)
            {
                writeStream.WriteByte((byte)i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It is wired in `WebApiConfig` like so:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.Formatters.Clear();
        config.Formatters.Add(new SomeFormatter());

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

and a Web API controller :

```
public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    public SomeResponse Get(SomeRequest request)
    {
        return new SomeResponse();
    }
}
```

yet when I test the controller with a GET (from a browser) I get a `null` request. The `CanReadType` fires and returns true but then none of the ReadFromStreamAsync overloads fire.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It was the content-type header (or lack of).

Although the formatter was inquired if it is able to deserialize this `Type`, it failed the next check, namely to see if it supports the content-type supplied, or in case it was not supplied, `application/octet-stream`.

All that was needed was this:

```
public class SomeFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{
    public SomeFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));
    }

...

}
```